# Including helper method in controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do i include some helper into my controller_spec code?
I have method called "a_title(ads)" in dates_ads_helper, and returns self.
How do i use this method in my controller_spec test?

When i try to call it in my controller_spec file i'm getting this error

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `a_title'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the helper methods already included in the template engine:

Rails 2: use the @template variable.
Rails 3: has the nice controller method view_context
Usage of a_title

```
# rails 3 sample
def controller_action
  @price = view_context.a_title( 42.0 ) 
end

# rails 2 sample
def controller_action
  @price = @template.a_title( 42.0 ) 
end
```

If you want to share a method between a helper and a controller you can define via helper method:

```
class SomeController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :my_shared_method
  ...

  def my_shared_method
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

Regards!